# Factory pattern using dependency injection

Tags: java, dependency-injection

I find myself doing the following fairly regularly:

```
@Component
class FactoryOne {

    public Object getNewMyThing() {
        return new Object();
    }
}

@Component
class FactoryTwo {

    @Autowired
    FactoryOne factoryOne;

    public Object getNewMyThingTwo() {
        Object one = factoryOne.getNewMyThing();
        return new MyThingTwo(one);
    }
}
```

**FactoryOne does actually depend on JIT values to produce its object instance, although the example doesn't show this.**

FactoryTwo is dependent on some JIT thing that factory one produces, however, whenever I write this code, I look at it and think "I must be able to let the DI framework handle this for me".

...is there a code pattern I can use to handle this?

(Example is in Spring, but happy for an answer in any DI framework)

Comment: What exactly do you want to change? Your code looks fine.

Comment: @Tunaki - I guess the question I am asking, is there anything that will help me avoid creating `FactoryTwo`, since all its doing is calling other factories to get constructor arguments for the object its factory created. See edit.

Comment: I'm confused. If you can't can Spring instantiate `FactoryOne` through a `@Component` annotation, define a `@Bean` method for it or create a `FactoryBean` for `FactoryOne`.